# How to get node-to-node shortest path with Dijkstra ? (with adjacency list and specify start-node and end-node)

Tags: python, dijkstra

I have been working on a project using Dijkstra.

I would like to test Dijkstra with my own graph and in this case I'm using an implementation I took from Geeksforgeeks:

https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/dijkstras-algorithm-for-adjacency-list-representation-greedy-algo-8/

Output

```
Vertex   Distance from Source
0          0
1          4
2          12
3          19
4          21
5          11
6          9
7          8
8          14
```

In this case this implementation give me the value of the distance but I want to get the shortest path node-to-node and  specify the start-node and the end-node.

Answer (score 0):

One simple way I suggest is to keep an additional data structure to store the parent of relationship between 2 vertices. So basically whenever you update the tentative distance of an unsettled vertex v by edge (u,v) (ps:it indicates the current vertex in the iteration is u), you store/update this relationship that the source may reach v through u. If you later finder a shorter distance to v by edge (w,v), you have to update this relationship. So after you settle the destination vertex, you can use this data structure to retrieve the full node to node shortest path.